# How do I plot the solutions and errors obtained through Jacobi Iteration?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a figure showing the solution I obtained through Jacobi iteration along with the true solution, as well as the error of the Jacobi solution.

The figure I'm trying to create should consist of two plots.

I used the subplot command, to split the figure into
an upper and lower axes and I wrote the for loop that calculates the Jacobi iterations and the error. The loop is going to iterate 400 times using x0 as the initial guess. Before this, I calculated the true solution to the system Ax = b.

```
N = 30;
iter = 400;
A = toeplitz([-2 1 zeros(1, N-2)], [-2 1 zeros(1, N-2)]);
bk = ones(N,1);
for jj = 1:N
    bk(jj) = cos(5*jj) + (1/2)*sin(7*jj);
end
x = A\bk;
D = diag(diag(A));
T = A - D;
x0 = zeros(N,1);
error = zeros(iter,1);
M = -D\T;
g = D\bk;
for nn = 1:iter
    x0 = M*x0 + g;
    error(nn) = norm(x - x0,2);
end
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x0(1:N,1),'ro');
ylabel('Solution','FontSize',22);
title('Solution by Jacobi Iteration','FontSize',22);
xlim([0 pi]);
ylim([-5 5]);
xticks(0:0.5:3);
yticks(-5:5:5);
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(error(1:N),'ro')
ylabel('Error','FontSize',22);
xlabel('t','FontSize',22);
xlim([0 pi]);
ylim([0 0.1]);
xticks(0:0.5:3);
yticks(0:0.05:0.1);
```

The upper window should show the true solution in red circles connected by solid lines. The lower window show show the error as red
circles connected by dotted lines. When I ran my code, only 3 red circles appeared in the upper window and nothing was plotted in the lower window. I'm still bad at plotting iterations of a loop. Can someone help me with plotting the solutions and errors I calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xlim` and `ylim` statements are not representative of the data.

- `x0` and `x` have `N` elements (30 here), and the elements of `x` and `x0` span -2 to 2 in this setup.
- `error` has `iter` elements (400 here), and the elements of `error` go from 4 to about 0.01.

For these plots, the element index maps to the horizontal x-axis, and their values to the y-axis.  I think this plot setup should give you the result you desire (I probably changed more than actually needed):

```
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(1:N, x0(1:N,1), 'ro', 1:N, x,'k+');
title('Solution by Jacobi Iteration','FontSize',22);

ylabel('Solution','FontSize',22);
xlim([1, N]);
ylim([-3, 3]);
xticks(1:N);
yticks(-3:0.5:3);

subplot(2,1,2)
semilogy(1:iter, error(1:iter),'ro')
ylabel('Error','FontSize',22);
xlabel('t','FontSize',22);
xlim([1 iter]);
ylim([0 4]);
xticks(0:25:400);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but my intended axis values and limits were supposed to be what I wrote in my original code.

Comment: @ArataKaizaki, okay. `ylim([-5 5]);` is fine since `x0`'s values fall in that range, but `xlim([0 pi]);` doesn't make sense currently since `x0` is plotted against its index. Likewise for `error`, it will be less than 0.1, but the index is inherently 1 to `iter`. Unless there is some other context to this problem, the limits don't make sense.